# I want to group list of list

Tags: c#, linq

The structure of class along with sample data here.

```
class Student
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; } 

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Int32 Age { get; set; }

    public List<string> subjects { get; set; }

}

class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] )
    {
        List<Student> students = new List<Student>()
        {
           new Student(){ Id=1 ,Name="Pratik", Age=24, subjects=new List<string>(){"s1", "s2"}},
           new Student(){ Id=2, Name="Ashish", Age=28, subjects=new List<string>{"s1", "s4"}},
           new Student(){ Id=3, Name="Umesh", Age=24, subjects=new List<string>(){"s1" }},
           new Student(){ Id=4, Name="Ajay", Age=28, subjects=new List<string>(){"s5", "s1"}},
           new Student(){ Id=5, Name="Vijay", Age=24, subjects=new List<string>(){"s1"}},
           new Student(){ Id=6, Name="Shital", Age=24, subjects=new List<string>(){"s2", "s3"}}
        };

        ...
    }
```

I want to group `subjects` on `Names` for ex.

```
s2 Pratik, Shital
```

Comment: what is the desired result and why?

Comment: You said list of list, but there is only one list that I see.

Answer (score 1):

[Demo on dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/THpo7p)

1. Using `SelectMany` to get list of list item with format like `{ Name, Subject }`
2. Using `GroupBy` to group `Subject` and Using `Join` to get list of Names seperated by comma.

```
var data = students.SelectMany(p => p.subjects.Select(s => new { p.Name, Subject = s  }));
var result = data.GroupBy(p => p.Subject)
                .Select(g => new 
                { 
                    g.Key, 
                    Names = string.Join(",", g.Select(n => n.Name))  
                });
```

**Output**

```
s1 Pratik,Ashish,Umesh,Ajay,Vijay
s2 Pratik,Shital
s4 Ashish
s5 Ajay
s3 Shital
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @Pratik Gosatwar

Comment: @Pratik Gosatwar If my answer was helpful to you, you should accept it by clicking the checkmark https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group on `subjecs` yous should *flatten* with a help of `SelectMany` before `GroupBy`:

```
   var result = students
     .SelectMany(student => student.subjects.Select(subject => new {
        subject,
        student 
      })) 
     .GroupBy(item => item.subject, 
              item => item.student)
     .OrderBy(group => group.Key);  // Let's order by subjects' names
```

Having `student`s  grouped by `subject`, you can easily add `Select`. For instance, let's print out students' `Names` who attend each subject:

```
  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result
    .Select(group => $"{group.Key} : {string.Join(", ", group.Select(s => s.Name))}"));

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
s1 : Pratik, Ashish, Umesh, Ajay, Vijay
s2 : Pratik, Shital
s3 : Shital
s4 : Ashish
s5 : Ajay
```

Answer (score 0):

I would select names where the subject matched.

```
var matches = students.Where(x => x.subjects.Contains("s2")).Select(y => y.Name);
var names = string.Join(",", matches);
```